# HTTPClient PostMethod for byte[]

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I need to send a byte[] to rest web service end point and I was wondering how to setup the request using HTTPClient's PostMethod, any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ByteArrayEntity](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/ByteArrayEntity.html) should be what your're looking for:

```
 [...]
 PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
 post.setRequestEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(bytes));
 post.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
 [...]
```

You will have to set `content-type` to match what you have in the byte array.

Comment: +1 for pointing out you need to set the `Content-Type`. I totally missed that before and it messed me up.